# Spring disable context:component-scan does not detect controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application is correctly running with:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage">  </context:component-scan>
```

When I replace this by the manual bean definition the Controllers are not detected anymore.

In any of the cases I'm using those annotations:

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

The autowired methods of the controllers are called but the beans are not declared as entrypoints, thus, 404 error and not accessible.

What is the black magic behind component scan?

Controllers are declared like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Controller configuration -->
    <bean class="com.xx.ControllerClass" />

</beans>
```

Comment: How exactly do you replace it with manual bean definition? Do you define controllers?

Comment: I just define beans. It should be ok, shouldn't?

Comment: Do you understand that controllers are beans too?

Comment: What I say is that I don't explicitly declare de controllers. I've just created an applicationContext-controller.xml and included de controllers as beans. Then I expect spring to see that those are controllers by detecting the annotation @RequestMapping.

Comment: Why are you going back to declaring beans for your controllers instead of annotations? Using annotations does a lot for you that you'd otherwise have to do manually via configuration. These steps are probably what you're missing, but there's not enough information to determine what's wrong. Can we see your controller classes? Are they extending the AbstractController class or some other implementation of the Controller interface?

Comment: Cause I have a limit of startup time and component scanning is slowing it down. I think the problem is where to declare de controllers: inside dispatcher-servlet.xml or applicationcontext. What is the difference?

Comment: Is this like transactions, where they need to be in the same file?  Try adding annotation-driven to the file with the controllers defined, see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speculation based on your comments - you have declared the beans for your controllers in a applicationContext-controllers.xml file, now is this file imported in the web application Context file, the one that you declare with the DispatcherServlet web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-controller.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If it is not, then that is probably the issue. There are typically two different application contexts for a Spring MVC based application, the one that you declare using ContextLoaderListener(the Root Web application Context) and the web related beans declared through DispatcherServlet, your Controllers, `mvc:annotation-driven` etc need to be in the web related beans declaration.

Comment: That's the solution. I thought everything was in the same context. Thanks.